# Using multiple conditions in firebase rules and accessing with if statement not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have multiple conditions in my firebase rules and want to access the data base on the current user by using if statement in my return statement. When I access it individually, it works but when I use if statements, I don't get the data but permission error issue.

I've tried accessing it but keeps failing.

My rule:

```
"query.orderByChild == 'userId' && query.equalTo == auth.uid || 
root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() === 'admin'"
```

Accessing the data:

```
let db = firebase.database().ref(`/items`).orderByChild('userId').equalTo(currentUser.uid)

if(firebase.database().ref('/admins').child(currentUser.uid).child('role').equalTo('admin')) {
  db = firebase.database().ref(`/items`)
 }

db
.once('value')
.then(snapshot => {
    let doc = []
    const data = snapshot.val();
    for (let key in data) {

      doc.push({
        ...data[key],
        key: key
      });
    }
```

Ideally, I would like to have a rule with OR and have an if/else statement to return data depending on the user.

Comment: None of your code that accesses the data is actually accessing any data.  You have to use `once()` or `on()` to actually invoke the query and get a snapshot back.  That `if` statement isn't at all doing what you might expect.  It's just checking the "truthiness" of an object, which is always going to be true.

Comment: @Frank, I didn't include the code with `once()`, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

This statement does not do what you think it does:

```
if(firebase.database().ref('/admins').child(currentUser.uid).child('role').equalTo('admin'))
```

Nothing in this line reads from the database, and the `equalTo` merely **builds** a query, it does not actually perform any check.

If you want to to check whether the user is an admin:

```
let userRoleRef = firebase.database().ref('/admins').child(currentUser.uid).child('role');
userRoleRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  if ('admin' == snapshot.val()) {
    db = firebase.database().ref(`/items`)

    ... continue using db here
  }
}
```

Now the client-side query and the server-side security rules work in tandem to ensure the user only requests and only can get the data that they're authorized for.

Comment: This is only doing a client-side verification of the user role. You should use firebase security rules to restrict the data that is only accessible to admins

Comment: Hey @SimonTran. The question already contains the security rules that OP uses, and there was no problem with those rules. The problem they asked about came from their code, which is why I only showed how to update their code in my answer. I'd appreciate it if you could remove your downvote on my answer.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to specify that the right way to secure this database would be to use firebase rules? I believe that your answer could mislead people into simply filtering client-side

Comment: Done. Of course going forward, you could also post your own answer that focuses on that part of answering OPs question. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯